# How do I delete mail from /var/mail/user specified by a date range?

Tags: mail

I have a whole lot of mail in my /var/mail/user file. Is there some way I can delete all the mail generated in 2016 only?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`mutt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man1/mutt.1.html) for this purpose. It is a small but very powerful text based program for reading and sending electronic mail:

```
sudo apt install mutt
```

The steps are:

- Run `mutt` in to a terminal.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - *delete-pattern* - delete messages matching a pattern.
- Type the pattern: `~d 01/01/2016-31/12/2016` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You could use also the pattern `~d 1/16-12/16`. Where `~d [MIN]-[MAX]` means *messages with “date-sent” in a Date range*.
- Press <kbd>q</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

[image]

Other useful patterns according to the current topic could be:

- `~d>30d` - will delete the messages older than 30 days.
- `~m 120-234` - will delete the messages with numbers in the range `123` to `234`.

References:

- [NeoMutt Guide:Advanced Usage](https://www.neomutt.org/guide/advancedusage.html)
- [Mutt:Deleting messages older than 30 days](https://slaptijack.com/software/mutt-deleting-messages-older-than-30-days/)
- [How do I delete messages specified by a number range?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162898/how-do-i-delete-messages-specified-by-a-number-range)

Comment: The pattern is `~d>30d` no spaces.

Comment: Hi, @MartinT. Thanks for the comment. Probably at the version I've made the tests 3 years earlier the syntax was with spaces. However, if you find this answer useful, don't forgot to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `procmail` to generate a new file.  Normally you would file your mail as you work.

There are a number of email clients that you can use.  Many allow you to select multiple messages to file or delete.