# Confusion over the location of mail location

Tags: email, mutt

I have alpine installed on my system and I installed mutt to use its methods to delete older emails. I might have done something wrong and I that /var/mail/userid is empty now (file size is 0), but "alpine" shows all the emails. Where is alpine storing the email files.

I was trying the suggestion given here: [How do I delete mail from /var/mail/user specified by a date range?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/978883/how-do-i-delete-mail-from-var-mail-user-specified-by-a-date-range)

Comment: **Close voters:**  The questioner means this: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/alpine.1.html, **not** Alpine Linux.